# Impute missing value with mean from last two days - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For each dimension I'd like to impute missing values with the mean of the last two previous days that don't contain null values. Please see examples below:

Main_DF

```
date        portal_name      price_category  avg_price   total_sales
2020-01-01  british_airways  business_class  4310        6312
2020-01-01  british_airways  economy_class   1200        12432
2020-01-01  british_airways  first_class     8990        2313
2020-01-02  british_airways  business_class  4564        5423
2020-01-02  british_airways  economy_class   1145        14242
2020-01-02  british_airways  first_class     9533        2210
2020-01-03  british_airways  business_class              
2020-01-03  british_airways  economy_class   1145        14242
2020-01-03  british_airways  first_class       
2020-01-04  british_airways  business_class              
2020-01-04  british_airways  economy_class   1321        17334
2020-01-04  british_airways  first_class
```

Output_DF

```
date        portal_name      price_category  avg_price   total_sales
2020-01-01  british_airways  business_class  4310        6312
2020-01-01  british_airways  economy_class   1200        12432
2020-01-01  british_airways  first_class     8990        2313
2020-01-02  british_airways  business_class  4564        5423
2020-01-02  british_airways  economy_class   1145        14242
2020-01-02  british_airways  first_class     9533        2210
2020-01-03  british_airways  business_class  4437        5868    
2020-01-03  british_airways  economy_class   1145        14242
2020-01-03  british_airways  first_class     9261        2262    
2020-01-04  british_airways  business_class  4437        5868   
2020-01-04  british_airways  economy_class   1321        17334
2020-01-04  british_airways  first_class     9261        2262
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can use `groupby` and `transform` with `tail(2)` to get the last two days:

```
df[["avg_price", "total_sales"]] = (df.groupby("price_category")
                                      .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x[x.notnull()].tail(2).mean())))

print (df)

          date      portal_name  price_category  avg_price  total_sales
0   2020-01-01  british_airways  business_class     4310.0       6312.0
1   2020-01-01  british_airways   economy_class     1200.0      12432.0
2   2020-01-01  british_airways     first_class     8990.0       2313.0
3   2020-01-02  british_airways  business_class     4564.0       5423.0
4   2020-01-02  british_airways   economy_class     1145.0      14242.0
5   2020-01-02  british_airways     first_class     9533.0       2210.0
6   2020-01-03  british_airways  business_class     4437.0       5867.5
7   2020-01-03  british_airways   economy_class     1145.0      14242.0
8   2020-01-03  british_airways     first_class     9261.5       2261.5
9   2020-01-04  british_airways  business_class     4437.0       5867.5
10  2020-01-04  british_airways   economy_class     1321.0      17334.0
11  2020-01-04  british_airways     first_class     9261.5       2261.5
```